# How to display a complete trip with multiple routes using Google Map API's Direction Requests in one single page and display them all?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Ok, here's the thing.
I tried to display a whole trip containing visiting multiple locations by displaying every route in it. For example: I may start from New York, then go to Boston, then LA, then San Francisco and at last back to NYC.

Here's part of the code of having a loop with multiple requests and displaying the routes in their order.

```
        for (int i=0; i<all; ++i) {
        System.out.println(places.get(pass.charAt(i)-48)+"to"+places.get(pass.charAt(i+1)-48));
    %>
        var start = "<%=places.get(pass.charAt(i)-48) %>";
        var end = "<%=places.get(pass.charAt(i+1)-48) %>";
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          provideRouteAlternatives: false,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            if (first == 1) {
                first = 0;
                responseAll = response;
                responseAll.routes[<%=i%>] = response.routes[0];
            }else {
                responseAll.routes[<%=i%>] = response.routes[0];
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(responseAll);
            }           
          }
        });
    <%}%>
```

The problem is that somehow it just displays the first three routes I request. In this case, the route of NYC to Boston, Boston to LA, LA to San Francisco.
I thought it might be that the page can at most display three routes. So i tested this thought by changing the code into this(which initialize the DirectionResponse with 5 routes in it)

```
                if (first == 1) {
                first = 0;
                responseAll = response;
                for (var a = 0; a!=5;++a) {
                    responseAll.routes[a] = response.routes[0];
                }
```

And then I found that it can display more than 5 routes at the same time(which though in this test case they are all the same routes). So it turns out to be it ignoring the other requests after the third one.

So here's my question: is there anyway to fix it to have it answering all the requests, or is to say more than three requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can make a single request with multiple "stopover" waypoints (up
  to 8, plus the origin, and destination).

[example of multiple routes combined](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html)

- You are not examining the value of the returned status, the way your
  code is currently written, if the directions request fails (status
  != OK), you don't get informed.  Either examine the value of status
  in a debugger or try adding a check that lets you know why it failed.  Something like this might help (not tested):

  ```
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      if (first == 1) {
          first = 0;
          responseAll = response;
          responseAll.routes[<%=i%>] = response.routes[0];
      }else {
          responseAll.routes[<%=i%>] = response.routes[0];
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(responseAll);
      }           
    } else { 
      alert("Directions request failed, status = "+status);
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your useful advise!
For the first one, it's not gonna work for my traveling mode here is TRANSIT so...
And the second one is very helpful. It did alert two times for OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, which means precisely that it accepted my first three requests and rejected the other two. My question is how to have all those five requests answered. Thanks

Comment: For the second part of your comment. Look at the solutions that have been posted to SO for dealing with OVER_QUERY_LIMIT (you need to delay, then retry).

Answer (score -1):

I think KML might be helpful for you while mixing with API.